# VBA Excel Loop to Delete Range Based on Value in Column C

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am trying to delete a specific range based on whether or not column "C" meets specific criteria.

Currently I have the following:

```
If Range("C69") = "All values USD Millions." Then
    Range("C69 : H69").Delete shift:=xlUp
Else Range("A3").Select
End If
```

I want to turn this into a loop that will search cells "C1" through "C100" for the words "All values USD Millions." and delete the corresponding C though H range. For example, if it found the value in "C15", it would delete Range("C15:H15").

Unfortunately, I am still learning and all the loops I try create an error.

Comment: Do you want to just delete data or delete rows?

Comment: [See Documentation vba loops](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1873/flow-control-structures/8166/for-each-loop#t=201704142028043832034)

Comment: @Michael Shore have you tried any of the solutions provided below ? any feedback ?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. I tried @june7's solution, and it has worked seamlessly.

Comment: If an answer resolves issue would be nice to mark it accepted.

Comment: My bad--did not realize. Will make sure to do so going forward. I accepted your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to delete cells from columns A and B, this works for me:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 100
    If Range("C" & i) = "All values USD Millions." Then
        Range("C" & i & ":H" & i).Delete
    Else
        Range("A3").Select
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the filtering capability of Excel:

```
With Sheet1.Range("C1:H100")
    .AutoFilter 1, "All values USD Millions."
    .Offset(1).Delete
    .AutoFilter
End With
```

However if you want to do a "classic" iteration and delete while iterating on the rows, remember always that in these cases you should iterate *"backward"*:

```
Dim i as long
For i = Range("C999999").End(xlUp).Row to 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "C").Value2 = "All values USD Millions." Then Rows(i).Delete
Next
```

Comment: you can use Cells(Rows.Count,"C").End(xlUp).row in place of `C999999`

Comment: Definitely use `AutoFiler`, or maybe `Find` function - we're always watching ;)

Answer (score 2):

Another fast way, without looping throughout the rows one by one, is using the `Find` function:

```
Option Explicit

Sub UseFindFunc()

Dim FindRng         As Range
Dim Rng             As Range
Dim LastRow         As Long
Dim TexttoFind      As String

TexttoFind = "All values USD Millions." ' <-- try to use variable, easy to modify later

With Sheet1
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row '<-- get last row with data in Column C
    Set Rng = .Range("C1:H" & LastRow)

    Set FindRng = Rng.Find(What:=TexttoFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    While Not FindRng Is Nothing '<-- find was successful
        FindRng.Resize(, 5).Delete xlShiftUp '<-- delete column "C:H" in found row
        Set FindRng = Rng.Find(What:=TexttoFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Wend
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
For i=1 to 100
    If Cells (i, 3) = "All values USD Millions." Then

        Rows (i).Delete
        i = i - 1 ' Needed to test shifted row value after a deleted row
    EndIf
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is not as static you could do the script till your last row or set i = 1 to 100 to stop at row 100

```
    Sub test()
    Dim lRow As Long

     lRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row, 
     Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Row, Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row)

    With ActiveSheet
    For i = lRow To 2 Step -1
    If .Cells(i, "C").Value = "All values USD Millions." Then
      Range("C" & i & ":H" & i).ClearContents
    End If
   Next i
   End With


   End Sub
```